# How can I get a bot to respond to a channel mention?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a bot that is used for archiving and organization of channels. I am trying to get it to perform some code when someone mentions a channel so that it moves the message to the channel it belongs in but I can't get it to respond to the channel mention.

I thought it would be something like this

```
if (message.content == "<#ChannelID>") {
            do things  
    }
```

Comment: I don't know much about discord but I think you will have to provide more details so that the community can help you.

Comment: Try something like `let mentionedChannels = channelList.filter(chanel => message.content.contains(channel.name));`

Answer (score 1):

There is [`message.mentions.channels`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=mentions) for that purpose. Thats a Map, so you can check for a channel with [`.has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/has).

Comment: would that look like

`if (message.mentions.channels.has("<#ChannelID>"))`

Comment: @potatoman23 The channels in the `message.mentions.channels` Collection are mapped by their ID. That means that your condition should be `message.mentions.channels.has('channelID')`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the `includes` method.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach I would take as I mentioned in my comment.

```js
// array of channels that you are monitoring and looking for
const channelList = [
 {name: 'Channel1', roomId: 1},
 {name: 'Channel2', roomId: 2},
 {name: 'Channel3', roomId: 3},
 {name: 'Channel4', roomId: 4},
 {name: 'Channel5', roomId: 5},
]

function test() {
 let msg = document.getElementById('test').value || '';
  console.log('mentioned channels', channelList.filter(channel => msg.toLowerCase().indexOf(channel.name.toLowerCase()) > -1))
}
```

```html
<span>Type your sample message in the textbox and click test.</span><br />
<input type="text" id="test" />
<button onclick="test()">test</button>
```